# Object tracking by kinect on raspberry pi

Tags: python, opencv, kinect

I m working on object tracking with kinect on a raspberry pi.
I mix 2 code because I need to find nearly object with kinect and then use OpenCV filter to setup gray color after this process tracking gray object!
but I can't! please help me

```
import freenect
import cv2
import numpy as np

"""
Grabs a depth map from the Kinect sensor and creates an image from it.
"""
def getDepthMap():  
depth, timestamp = freenect.sync_get_depth()

np.clip(depth, 0, 2**10 - 1, depth)
depth >>= 2
depth = depth.astype(np.uint8)

return depth

while True:
depth = getDepthMap()
#text_file = codecs.open("log2.txt", "a","utf-8-sig")
#text_file.write(str(depth)+'\n')

depth = getDepthMap()
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(depth, (5, 5), 0)
cv2.imshow('image', blur)
```

This code can show me object in 2 color : black and white 
black is nearly ---
I want to mix this code to object tracking. but icant.

```
# find contours in the mask and initialize the current
# (x, y) center of the ball
cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
center = None

# only proceed if at least one contour was found
if len(cnts) > 0:
    # find the largest contour in the mask, then use
    # it to compute the minimum enclosing circle and
    # centroid
    c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
    ((x, y), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
    M = cv2.moments(c)
    center = (int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]), int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]))

    # only proceed if the radius meets a minimum size
    if radius > 10:
        # draw the circle and centroid on the frame,
        # then update the list of tracked points
        cv2.circle(frame, (int(x), int(y)), int(radius),
            (0, 255, 255), 2)
        cv2.circle(frame, center, 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)

# update the points queue
pts.appendleft(center)
```

http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/14/ball-tracking-with-opencv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic in your code seems to be right. I noticed some implementation errors, though.

First, you should indent the block after `while True`. You should also add a call to `waitKey()` so that OpenCV doesn't get stuck at `imshow()`:

```
while True:
    depth = getDepthMap()
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(depth, (5, 5), 0)
    cv2.imshow('image', blur)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Finally, you should associate the input of the next block (`mask`) with the output of the previous one (`blur`):

```
mask = blur
```