# Using the kinect depth camera to track a ball in python

Tags: python, opencv, kinect, openkinect

I am looking to create a project similar to this one https://ptolemy.berkeley.edu/projects/chess/eecs149/fall2014/projects/_Report/Ball%20is%20Life.pdf and I am trying to track a ball using only the depth sensor on Kinect v1. However, I am unable to get accurate results. I am using OpenCV with python and I am using contours to try and locate the ball. I have tried using many filtering methods such as background subtraction and thresholding, but there is a lot of noise which led to false results.

This is an image sample as seen through the depth camera. The circular object is the ball.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4waE.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the kinect depth camera for a few projects, and TA'd a project where the student used a kinect to track a hand skeleton.

In all these projects, controlling the environment and some thresholds (x,y, and z) were needed to produce a semblance of accuracy. By this, I mean you should define a 'box' where you will attempt to find/track the ball. As well, adding a median or gaussian filter step may help you reduce the noise issues.

For other tracking algorithms/approaches, check out these resources:

- [Object tracking by kinect on raspberry pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44824205/object-tracking-by-kinect-on-raspberry-pi)
- http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/14/ball-tracking-with-opencv/
- https://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/
- https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghcircles/py_houghcircles.html